# Using .jss without a library

Tags: javascript, css, jss

I'm trying to use jss (or any "css in js" library) library without React and without compiling it in node (i'm using a visual studio project).

I've found the jss.js file but without any plugin, it's almost impossible to use.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i used the js file found here: https://unpkg.com/jss@9.8.1/dist/jss.js

then in my ts file i managed to do some examples that i found on the website but i can't get to use their plugins